Dirac sea and Klein Paradox
Can the Dirac sea model be used to explain the Klein paradox? Particularly the fact that the reflection current becomes bigger then one $\frac{j_{ref}}{j_{inc}}>1$ and the transmission current not being 0 even in the case of infinitely large potential barrier (in value) $\frac{j_{trans}}{j_{inc}}<0$
If yes, how exactly it is explained via the Dirac sea model?

I would think that the Klein paradox cannot be explained without understanding the Dirac sea.

@Buzz I could not disagree more

No, you can have the Klein paradox for bosons as well (simplest case would be scalars), for which the Dirac sea does not apply
